# Administrative page practices for web services. Does it really need to be on the same project?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, admin

I've made quite a few web services over the years, and all of them had admin pages, which either could only be accessed by users with proper roles or all together different "admin accounts".

In all the cases, I made some scope in the main project, and made sure non authorized users couldn't access the pages, it works fine.

However I always had the urge to completely part the entire feature into another service, or even create a minimal desktop app that would access restricted APIs.

I know its pretty much pointless overhead to do something like that, but in such instances like having two developers working on the main site and admin site, or security demands that there are to be no browser friendly way to access administrative features, or well just for the sake of it, I was wondering if there are any cases that the administrative pages have been separated from the main web service.

Any examples or design patterns on the subject are welcome.

Comment: Whether you use the main service or a separate one, would it not be the case that access to the admin page would still be protected by a regular login?

Comment: security wise its not a problem, its more of a development issue, at the least I haven't seen any services that separate admin and other pages